# Gulp version 5.0

Tags: javascript, gulp, desarrollo

Recientemente gulp se ha actualizado a una versión 5.0 que aunque se instala sin problemas no permite la utilización de la mayoría de los plugins. Creo que es debido a la forma que hago la llamada a los mismos. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar al respecto?.

Adjunto gulpfile que estoy utilizando y que con la versión de gulp 4.0.2 funciona sin problema. Muchas gracias.

---

```
const {src, dest, watch, series} = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

function css( done ) {
    src('src/scss/app.scss')
        .pipe( sass() )
        .pipe( dest('build/css') ) 
    done();
}
function dev( ) {
    watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', css);
    watch('src/img/**/*', )
    
}
exports.dev = dev;
```

---